# NestJS Views Not gettings added to Dist

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

My folder structure is similar to below.

```
public
views
src
  main.ts
  /users
       users.controller.ts
       /views
         my-view.hbs
  /books
       books.controller.ts
       /views
         my-view.hbs
```

This is what i use to add the templates and views

```
 const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
    AppModule,
  );
  console.log(join(__dirname, 'public'));

  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
  app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
  app.setViewEngine('hbs');
  hbs.registerPartials(join(__dirname, '..', 'views', 'partials'));
```

My package.json scripts looks like this

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/src/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
```

My issue is that when i run nest in dev mode it builds the distribution code and it doesn't add the views and the public folder.

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same problem and I've figured out that `"assets"` should be inside `"compilerOptions"`, did you confirm the same?

I did make it work like this:

```json
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "webpack": false,
    "assets": [
      "**/*.hbs"
    ],
    "watchAssets": true
  },
  "generateOptions": {
    "spec": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Check [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#assets) section in the official documentation.

With `assets`, `nest build` will distribute non-TypeScript files, such as `.graphql` files, images, `.html` files and other assets as part of your development build step.

Example:

```
"assets": ["**/*.hbs"]
```

Add this to your `nest-cli.json` file located in the root directory.

Comment: this does not worked  for me.  It still does not move views folder to dist.

Comment: "assets" should be **inside** "compilerOptions". Answer from Andre Mota is more complete and accurate.

Comment: refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70094884/2153187

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue.
The thing is that the function join that you use for setting the path for the folders is literaly joining the strings inside of it.
So, in my case, my views and public folders were outside the src folder.

My line was:
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
I changed it to:
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'src/public'));

And that solve my problem.

Comment: what is __dirname here? are you in `src`? if so, join(__dirname, '..', 'public') backs you up one directory (because of '..'), then moves to 'public'. If your __dirname is `src`, you second line backs you out of src then puts you back in it with `src/public`. It seems that your `public` dir is within `src` meaning your first line could be `app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, 'public'))`