# Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory NestJs

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I am getting the following error from nestjs:

```
Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/api/dist/views"
```

I am trying to use handlebars templating engine with NestJs. I have followed the NestJs documentation [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc) directly without changing a thing. For some weird reason i still get the same error.

I have even created a fresh project using the `nestjs cli`, followed the direction in the documentation above and still getting thesame error.

I have also followed the help in this stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60630960/nestjs-views-not-gettings-added-to-dist) and added `"assets": ["**/*.hbs"]` to my `nest-cli.json` at the root of the project. Still getting thesame error.

Can anyone help me please? or Has anyone experienced this or is it just me?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found a solution that helped me. Hope this saves a dev's life:

**First**

move `public` and `views` folder into your `src` folder

**Next**
in your `main.ts` file

`import {resolve } from 'path';`

**Then**

change this :

```
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
app.setViewEngine('hbs');
```

to this :

```
 app.useStaticAssets(resolve('./src/public'));
 app.setBaseViewsDir(resolve('./src/views'));
 app.setViewEngine('hbs');
```

you are good to go.

Comment: Thank You, It solves the problem, I am having an exactly a similar issue

Comment: I kept my public at root level and used`app.useStaticAssets(resolve('./public'))` and this worked too

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the sample from [NestJs documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc), and another from the project I'm working on using Docker. The one from the sample worked just fine but I got the same error in the Dockerized project. I got that solved by adding this to the project's pipeline:

```
docker cp public {container-name}:/usr/app/dist
docker cp views {container-name}:/usr/app/dist
```

Just replace the path with the workspace from the Dockerfile. I hope this helps those getting the same problem with Dockerize app.