# NestJS - assets & views folder not being added to dist

Tags: nestjs

NestJS - assets & views folder not being added to dist folder after build

My folder structure is similar to below:

```
/assets
  /img
  /fonts

/views
  failure.hbs
  success.hbs

/src
  main.ts
  /users
       users.controller.ts
```

Comment: That is the regular behavior. Build compiles typescript codes under the src folder and creates the same folder structure for output js files in the dist folder. This could help you to keep same pathing.  You could directly take your folders like assets views and dist as same order to deployment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy non-ts files to dist when building typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306654/how-to-copy-non-ts-files-to-dist-when-building-typescript)

Answer (score 44):

You can copy those folders into the `dist` folder by adding these lines to your `nest-cli.json` file:

```json
  "compilerOptions": {    
    "assets": [
      {
        "include": "../assets",
        "outDir": "dist/public",
        "watchAssets": true
      },
      {
        "include": "../views",
        "outDir": "dist/views",
        "watchAssets": true
      }
    ],
    "watchAssets": true
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I came to this thread for NestJS + EJS Setup (late to the party) and below is my directory structure.

```
/views
  index.ejs

/src
  main.ts
```

> Note: after changing `compilerOptions` in "nest-cli.json" fixed the issue.

```
"compilerOptions": {    
    "assets": [
      {
        "include": "views",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "watchAssets": true
      }
    ],
    "watchAssets": true,
    "deleteOutDir": true
  }
```

Comment: thank. can we add package.json and node_modules and .env file in buils?

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure `nest-cli.json` is included while building the app (example: from Dockerfile)

Answer (score -1):

I added my own `build.js` script when running `yarn build`:

**`package.json`:**

```
"build": "nest build && node build.js"
```

It copies the views and assets folders into the dist build folder.

**`build.js`:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

copyFolderRecursiveSync('views', 'dist');
copyFolderRecursiveSync('assets', 'dist');

function copyFileSync(source, target) {
  let targetFile = target;

  // If target is a directory, a new file with the same name will be created
  if (fs.existsSync(target)) {
    if (fs.lstatSync(target).isDirectory()) {
      targetFile = path.join(target, path.basename(source));
    }
  }

  fs.writeFileSync(targetFile, fs.readFileSync(source));
}

function copyFolderRecursiveSync(source, target) {
  let files = [];

  // Check if folder needs to be created or integrated
  const targetFolder = path.join(target, path.basename(source));
  if (!fs.existsSync(targetFolder)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(targetFolder);
  }

  // Copy
  if (fs.lstatSync(source).isDirectory()) {
    files = fs.readdirSync(source);
    files.forEach(function (file) {
      const curSource = path.join(source, file);
      if (fs.lstatSync(curSource).isDirectory()) {
        copyFolderRecursiveSync(curSource, targetFolder);
      } else {
        copyFileSync(curSource, targetFolder);
      }
    });
  }
}
```